# Align minipage on right side

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I was thinking that this is a small matter, but I can't seem to get my head around this.

I want to create a legend, which sits on the right side of the page.
I created a `minipage` environment around the environment that I want to have on my right side and using `\begin{flushright}`. However, I can't add a title inside this minipage environment so that it gets displayed on top of the surrounded environment.

The MWE is just an example. I don't use a table in my case. So how do align my title right above the other environment, in this case the table?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\textwidth}
        Some Title.
        \begin{flushright}
            \begin{longtable}{ll}
                Bla & Bla \\
                Blubb & Blubb
            \end{longtable}

        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I, in fact, would use a `tabular` environment for the title and the text; for the text, a `p{<length>}` column (and `@{}` to remove the extra space); inside the `tabular`, the title can be centered using `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\hfill\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.5\linewidth}@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{Some title} \\
\lipsum[4]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this structure will be used several times, an environment can be defined; in the following example, the newly defined `myenv` environment has one mandatory argument (the title) and an optional argument (the width used to typeset the text with a default value of `0.5\linewidth`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}[2][.5\linewidth]
  {\par\hfill\tabular{@{}p{#1}@{}}
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#2} \\ }
  {\endtabular\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}{Some title}
\lipsum*[4]
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}[.8\linewidth]{Some title}
\lipsum*[4]
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the title spans more than one line, one could load the `array` package in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{array}
```

and then say

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[2][.5\linewidth]
  {\par\hfill\tabular{@{}p{#1}@{}}
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}>{\centering}p{#1}@{}}{#2} \\ }
  {\endtabular\par}
```

Comment: You're missing a "\" in your first example, it should read `{Some title} \\    \lipsum[4]` instead of `{Some title} \    \lipsum[4]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use 100% plain LaTeX with boxes and the `minipage` environment:

with showframe:
[image: output with showframe package]

without showframe (see example):
[image: output without showframe]

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\noindent% prevent the box to be shifted a bit to the right
\makebox[\textwidth][r]{% create a box, with it's content aligned to the right
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}% create a content half width
    \section{Some title}
    \lipsum[4]
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `varwidth` environment from [the `varwidth` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth) to create a box around the natural width of the content and use `\hfill`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I used the [the `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) package to show the margins (and you can see that the table is aligned to the right margin).
- The first `\hfill` ensures that the `varwidth` environment is aligned with the right margin.
- The subsequent `\hfill` are used to ensure that the title is centered.
- The `@{}` was added to eliminate the column padding to the right of the last column in the table.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9.0cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \hfill
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \hfill\null Some Title.\hfill\null
        \begin{longtable}{ll@{}}
            Bla & Bla \\
            Blubb & Blubb
        \end{longtable}
    \end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm. But the title is still not above the longtable environment (?).

Comment: If you want the title above just insert a blank line after the title. Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: If I add a linebreak after `some title` it is not on the right side anymore. It jumps to the left. I want to output that Gonzalo Medina's solution outputs.

Comment: @cherrung: Sorry, I misunderstood that requirement -- have updated the solution to correct the placement of the title.