# How to right align a minipage?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

How can I right align a minipage without using `ragged2e`?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60483/align-minipage-on-right-side .

Comment: By the way, `flushright` doesn't need `ragged2e`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without minipages that would produce odd interline spacing; also this allows page breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{leftbox}[1]
 {\itemize[
    nosep,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    rightmargin=\dimexpr\textwidth-#1\relax,
    itemindent=\parindent,
    listparindent=\parindent,
  ]\item[]\relax}
 {\enditemize}

\newenvironment{rightbox}[1]
 {\itemize[
    nosep,
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\textwidth-#1\relax,
    rightmargin=0pt,
    itemindent=\parindent,
    listparindent=\parindent,
  ]\item[]\relax}
 {\enditemize}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{leftbox}{10cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{leftbox}

\begin{rightbox}{10cm}
\lipsum[3]
\end{rightbox}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use an `\hfill` before the minipage:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}

\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there another way of flushing the minpage to the right without using `\begin{flushright}`?

Comment: Oops, I'm still sleeping... you can insert an `\hfill` before the minipage. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\raggedleft\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `adjustbox` to create the minipage and align it right, simply use `minipage=10cm,right` as keys. You might want to add some space (e.g. `\medskip`) between the paragraph before it because the result will be a hbox.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}

\medskip
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=10cm, right}
\blindtext
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the only answer that works inside enumerate. Useful for requirement elicitations