# How to right align minipage?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I tried (flushright) before minipage {.4\textwidth} the block of text is aligned on the right, but slightly off the edge - about 12pt to the left of the edge. I don't seem to be able to align it with the rest of the full width. I have \vspace{-9cm} ahead of flushright. The block appears in the correct position except it is off the edge. How can I fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please always show a complete example. `flushright` is an environment, if you  put the `minipage` environment inside it, then it will be flush to the right margin.

Comment: That's what I did, but it's not on the right margin. It's off.

Comment: Please, be so kind and show us what you try. The best in form of small but complete  document, which reproduce your problem.Now we can pnly guessing what you doing (wrong).

Comment: Try adding a blank line or `\par` after `\end{minipage}`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60483/align-minipage-on-right-side?rq=1 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408291/how-to-right-align-a-minipage?rq

Comment: if you show no code, no one can tell you what you did wrong.  edit the question with a code block that has a complete small document that shows the problem

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing ...

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document
    
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
   
\medskip 
\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      \lipsum[66]
      \end{minipage}
          
\medskip 
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The distance between the minipage and the following line isn't a full baseline; this may also be true between the first paragraph and the minipage (I didn't measure).  I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, but it needs fixing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right. Done.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: @DhirghamMurran, you are welcome! OBTW, if answer solve your problem you may consider to accept them (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of answer).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I am not too familiar with the web. Just new to it. I wanted to ask you  about hfill command. Small Minipage by default is always centered even though the \tabular{ l. r }. I tried to put hfill after minipage to make minipage align left, but it didn't work. It only works for aligning right. How can you align it on the left margin? The only trick I am familiar with is using tabular with two columns leaving the right columns empty by putting (& alone). Is there a better way?

Comment: @DhirghamMurran, it is hard to say anything since you not provide a document example which reproduce your problem. Si it is unclear, what you doing and what is your problem actually.  Minipages are not default centered. What you ask in question, is solved by my answer (you may consider to accept it ... ;-) ; BTW as I see so far you not accept any of received answers), however, if you have new problem, pleas ask new question,